# How to make BMP085 record Altitude every 30 Minutes?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I'm sending up a weather balloon for a science project with a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) attached to a [Adafriut BMP085](http://learn.adafruit.com/bmp085) and making it record and store an altitude reading using some C code. The only problem is that it currently only records it once, I want it when it's executed, it will record and store the Altitude in a text file every half an hour for approximately 24 hours or so. The code is right below.

Feel free to copy the code and reupload it with my parameters. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include "smbus.h" 

#define BMP085_I2C_ADDRESS 0x77

const unsigned char BMP085_OVERSAMPLING_SETTING = 3;

// Calibration values - These are stored in the BMP085
short int ac1;
short int ac2; 
short int ac3; 
unsigned short int ac4;
unsigned short int ac5;
unsigned short int ac6;
short int b1; 
short int b2;
short int mb;
short int mc;
short int md;

int b5; 

unsigned int temperature, pressure, altitude;


// Open a connection to the bmp085
// Returns a file id
int bmp085_i2c_Begin()
{
   int fd;
   char *fileName = "/dev/i2c-0";

   // Open port for reading and writing
   if ((fd = open(fileName, O_RDWR)) < 0)
      exit(1);

   // Set the port options and set the address of the device
   if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, BMP085_I2C_ADDRESS) < 0) {               
      close(fd);
      exit(1);
   }

   return fd;
}

// Read two words from the BMP085 and supply it as a 16 bit integer
__s32 bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(int fd, __u8 address)
{
   __s32 res = i2c_smbus_read_word_data(fd, address);
   if (res < 0) {
      close(fd);
      exit(1);
   }

   // Convert result to 16 bits and swap bytes
   res = ((res<<8) & 0xFF00) | ((res>>8) & 0xFF);

   return res;
}

//Write a byte to the BMP085
void bmp085_i2c_Write_Byte(int fd, __u8 address, __u8 value)
{
   if (i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(fd, address, value) < 0) {
      close(fd);
      exit(1);
   }
}

// Read a block of data BMP085
void bmp085_i2c_Read_Block(int fd, __u8 address, __u8 length, __u8 *values)
{
   if(i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data(fd, address,length,values)<0) {
      close(fd);
      exit(1);
   }
}


void bmp085_Calibration()
{
   int fd = bmp085_i2c_Begin();
   ac1 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xAA);
   ac2 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xAC);
   ac3 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xAE);
   ac4 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xB0);
   ac5 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xB2);
   ac6 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xB4);
   b1 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xB6);
   b2 = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xB8);
   mb = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xBA);
   mc = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xBC);
   md = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xBE);
   close(fd);
}

// Read the uncompensated temperature value
unsigned int bmp085_ReadUT()
{
   unsigned int ut = 0;
   int fd = bmp085_i2c_Begin();

   // Write 0x2E into Register 0xF4
   // This requests a temperature reading
   bmp085_i2c_Write_Byte(fd,0xF4,0x2E);

   // Wait at least 4.5ms
   usleep(5000);

   // Read the two byte result from address 0xF6
   ut = bmp085_i2c_Read_Int(fd,0xF6);

   // Close the i2c file
   close (fd);

   return ut;
}

// Read the uncompensated pressure value
unsigned int bmp085_ReadUP()
{
   unsigned int up = 0;
   int fd = bmp085_i2c_Begin();

   // Write 0x34+(BMP085_OVERSAMPLING_SETTING<<6) into register 0xF4
   // Request a pressure reading w/ oversampling setting
   bmp085_i2c_Write_Byte(fd,0xF4,0x34 + (BMP085_OVERSAMPLING_SETTING<<6));

   // Wait for conversion, delay time dependent on oversampling setting
   usleep((2 + (3<<BMP085_OVERSAMPLING_SETTING)) * 1000);

   // Read the three byte result from 0xF6
   // 0xF6 = MSB, 0xF7 = LSB and 0xF8 = XLSB
   __u8 values[3];
   bmp085_i2c_Read_Block(fd, 0xF6, 3, values);

   up = (((unsigned int) values[0] << 16) | ((unsigned int) values[1] << 8) | (unsigned int) values[2]) >> (8-BMP085_OVERSAMPLING_SETTING);

   return up;
}

// Calculate pressure given uncalibrated pressure
// Value returned will be in units of XXXXX
unsigned int bmp085_GetPressure(unsigned int up)
{
   int x1, x2, x3, b3, b6, p;
   unsigned int b4, b7;

   b6 = b5 - 4000;
   // Calculate B3
   x1 = (b2 * (b6 * b6)>>12)>>11;
   x2 = (ac2 * b6)>>11;
   x3 = x1 + x2;
   b3 = (((((int)ac1)*4 + x3)<<BMP085_OVERSAMPLING_SETTING) + 2)>>2;

   // Calculate B4
   x1 = (ac3 * b6)>>13;
   x2 = (b1 * ((b6 * b6)>>12))>>16;
   x3 = ((x1 + x2) + 2)>>2;
   b4 = (ac4 * (unsigned int)(x3 + 32768))>>15;

   b7 = ((unsigned int)(up - b3) * (50000>>BMP085_OVERSAMPLING_SETTING));
   if (b7 < 0x80000000)
      p = (b7<<1)/b4;
   else
      p = (b7/b4)<<1;

   x1 = (p>>8) * (p>>8);
   x1 = (x1 * 3038)>>16;
   x2 = (-7357 * p)>>16;
   p += (x1 + x2 + 3791)>>4;

   return p;
}

// Calculate temperature given uncalibrated temperature
// Value returned will be in units of 0.1 deg C
unsigned int bmp085_GetTemperature(unsigned int ut)
{
   int x1, x2;

   x1 = (((int)ut - (int)ac6)*(int)ac5) >> 15;
   x2 = ((int)mc << 11)/(x1 + md);
   b5 = x1 + x2;

   unsigned int result = ((b5 + 8)>>4);  

   return result;
}

// This Altitude part is stolen from some some unknown
// Arduino library.  The number divided into pressure for
// float A is derived from the local pressure as explained
// at http://learn.adafruit.com/bmp085/using-the-bmp085.
unsigned int bmp085_Altitude(float pressure)
{
   float A = pressure/101794.58;
   float B = 1/5.25588;
   float C = pow(A,B);
   C = 1 - C;
   C = C / 0.0000225577;

   return C;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)

{

   bmp085_Calibration();

   temperature = bmp085_GetTemperature(bmp085_ReadUT());
   pressure = bmp085_GetPressure(bmp085_ReadUP());
        altitude = bmp085_Altitude(pressure);

   printf("Temperature\t%0.1f *F\n", ((double)temperature)/10 * 1.8 + 32);
   printf("Pressure\t%0.2f hPa\n", ((double)pressure)/100);
        printf("Altitude\t%0.1f Feet\n", ((double)altitude)*3.280839895);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your target altitude? And do you have a blog/site/whatever for your project? Building a weather balloon sounds pretty interesting...

Comment: Our project is pretty private. It's for my final project in Science and a Science Fair. I've been sending up balloons for two years now, this is my first to take an Altitude Reading using a Raspberry Pi. We're planning to do a livestream during the launch, you can see our [Ustream Page](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/team-osi) for more info.

Comment: Well, if you have experience with weather balloons (which I obviously don't) you should not have any problem with the basics for the instrumentation package (power, thermal control e.t.c.). Good luck!

Comment: Yeah. Be sure to check out our live stream of the balloon in action. Should be online in March 2013.

Comment: I disagree with closing this, this is useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two potential solutions to your problem, if you do not need sub-second accuracy in the measurement intervals:

1. Wrap the contents of `main()` apart from the calibration in a loop and include a [`sleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) call with an argument of 1800 seconds:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       bmp085_Calibration();

      int count;

      for (count = 0; count < 49; ++count) {
          temperature = bmp085_GetTemperature(bmp085_ReadUT());
          pressure = bmp085_GetPressure(bmp085_ReadUP());
          altitude = bmp085_Altitude(pressure);

          printf("Temperature\t%0.1f *F\n", ((double)temperature)/10 * 1.8 + 32);
          printf("Pressure\t%0.2f hPa\n", ((double)pressure)/100);
          printf("Altitude\t%0.1f Feet\n", ((double)altitude)*3.280839895);

          sleep(1800);
      }

      return 0;
   }
   ```

   You may need to reset a few things for a second measurement to happen within the same program. You may also want to check the return value of `sleep()` to catch a potential premature end to that function call...
2. Since you are using Linux as the OS in your device, you can use a wrapper script around your program:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   while true; do
       /path/to/your/program >> measurements.log

       sleep 1800 
   done
   ```

   I will leave the termination after 48 hours as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: For your second solution, could I just execute your bash script and send it up? If so, this would be a great solution to my problem.

Comment: @sharksfan98: It should work, but you'd better do a couple of dry runs first...

Comment: Yes. I have two months until my initial launch for my new balloon, but I'll try to fit in a test launch or two between now and then.

Comment: @sharksfan98: well, I would suggest that you first try it on the ground once or twice :-) If it actually spans a day or two you should be able to use the temperature readings to verify that you *are* actually getting different measurements - comparing with ground-based instruments would also be a must. If you select a day with unstable weather you would also be able to check the barometric readings...

Comment: This is my eighth launch, 5 were successful and 2 crashed in a 15 mile radius of the launch point. This one only stands out cause we're trying to get more specific data, where the Raspberry Pi comes in.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you do not have any looping in your `MAIN()` routine. Since you want it to record the data every 30 minutes, you want MAIN to loop continuously, imo.

I don't know much/anything about Raspberry PI, I do know about Arduino however, and the main entry point routine is called automatically, which I presume is that same here, called `MAIN()`.

You could simple wrap the guts of `MAIN()` in a loop and use a sleep for 30 minutes. If you find that instead you wanted to do other activities while looping MAIN but still only want to record every 30 minutes, then you could store a variable `lastTimeDataStored` and compare that each time through loop; once its equal/greater than 30 minutes then store data and reset variable to current time.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)

{

   bmp085_Calibration();

   while (true) //loop indefinitely
   {
     temperature = bmp085_GetTemperature(bmp085_ReadUT());
     pressure = bmp085_GetPressure(bmp085_ReadUP());
     altitude = bmp085_Altitude(pressure);

     printf("Temperature\t%0.1f *F\n", ((double)temperature)/10 * 1.8 + 32);
     printf("Pressure\t%0.2f hPa\n", ((double)pressure)/100);
     printf("Altitude\t%0.1f Feet\n", ((double)altitude)*3.280839895);

     //either sleep for 30 minutes or check variable to see if 30 minutes has passed
     usleep((1000*60)*30); //sleep 30 minutes
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This answer helped a lot. :)